# Performance using JS querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When using JavaScript in the web browser is there any performance difference between the following:

Existing getElementById

```
document.getElementById("elem");
```

Query Selector using #id

```
document.querySelector("#elem");
```

Query Selector using [id=elem]

```
document.querySelector("[id=elem]");
```

I'm assuming the first one will be fastest (only has to lookup elements with an ID). Also the final one looks like bad practice. I like the second one as using querySelector for everything makes the code easy to read.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Test it](http://jsperf.com)

Comment: [Here's](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector) a quick link to the specific test

Comment: There is so many things which can influence this, how large is your DOM? How many child-parent-child nodes are their to traverse through in the DOM? Using the code in the question with a single element in the DOM makes no difference. Even the linked test is close to meaning-less. The question is more, when do you use which one? You can't use [**getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) when looking for a class obviously but you can do [**document.querySelector(".myclass")**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I think the OP specifically asked about ids. Obviously you would've used `getElementsByClassName` for classes.

Comment: @Bergi:Yes indeed :) `getElementsByClassName` is for classes, I only used the example given from the mozilla site when using `querySelector`. In regards to the question asking specifically for ids, well, use `getElementById` for retrieving elements by id and if one must use something else and compare performance, one should test it on a large more realistic DOM to make the test more accurate. Though as `getElementById` is there the question IMHO is not constructive.

Comment: Why is this question closed as "not constructive"? I came here as a developer to find out which one of those is faster!

Comment: A living link to a test: https://esbench.com/bench/57bdc462db965b9a00965c70 tl;dr `getElementById` is more than 10x faster.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly,

```
document.querySelector("#elem");
```

Has an advantage in the fact that, unlike document.getElementId, it can return classes. However, the usefulness of this is far diminished by the fact that it only returns the first object with that class name, so you might as well just use an id if you're not specifically looking for the first object with that classname. if you use,

```
document.querySelectorAll
```

However, I believe (I may be wrong), it returns all items with that classname as an array, where regular querySelector is equivalent to querySelectorAll[0]. One more advantage, is that you can run css3 queries through it, which can be quite useful.

Secondly,

```
document.getElementById("elem");
```

Has a very good advantage over queryselector in the sense that it is almost *5 times faster*, so if you're sitting there with several thousand lines of code and you want to optimise said code, then getElementById is the way to go.

Lastly,

```
document.querySelector("[id=elem]");
```

I, personally, don't see the need to use this in any situation. If you needed a querySelector, why not just use a # ? This is exactly equivalent to your first example of querySelector, however it has a lot of useless charaters.

Edit: Just to be clear, in summary, you're probably better off using document.getElementById.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it can return classes*"?

Comment: I mean, it can return classes: document.querySelector(".myclass");

Comment: Ah, you mean "it can return an element selected by class attributes". Of course, `getElementsByClassName` could do that as well.

Comment: However, it has an advantage of over getElementsByClassName in the sense that it can also return id's, as document.getElementById can.

Comment: Turns out `[id=elem]` could be useful when the id starts with a number, which is valid but requires escaping.

Comment: `[id=elem]` with `querySelectorAll` can be useful if multiple elements have the same id. They shouldn't, of course, but it does return all items in that situation, while `#elem` does not.

Answer (score 4):

[You can test it yourself](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector-vs-queryselector-by-id). getElementById is a fastest method

Comment: That link is down. Is there a working one?

Comment: https://esbench.com/bench/57bdc462db965b9a00965c70 Here is a living one, in case its get broken as well, the performance difference is more than 10x

Answer (score 3):

> is there any performance difference

Probably, since they are different functions. `querySelector` at least needs to parse the selector before detecting that it's equal to `getElementById`. And I doubt this optimisation takes place for the attribute selector at all, no one uses it. So I share your assumptions; and [tests confirm them](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector-vs-queryselector-by-id) (thanks to @Silver_Clash).

Personally I do not like the second one, as it is more ambiguous and awful to use with dynamic id values. Explicitly using `getElementById` is just more concise.