# In what cases should you use querySelector over getElementById?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, queryselector

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, HTML, and CSS, and while I was making a simple trivia website,and I noticed that when I tried comparing a users input to the expected text input using getElementById, it didn't work at all, once the code got to the part about comparing inputs, nothing happened. But when I switched it to querySelector, the code worked perfectly. Why is this?

The goal of the code was if the users input matched what the correct answer be, the textbox should become green and text should appear saying "Correct!". If they're wrong the textbox should turn red and text should say "Incorrect!".

My first code itteration looked like this, which didn't work.

```
    let check = document.getElementById("userInput");
        document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if(check.value == '26')
            {
                check.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
            }
            else
            {
                check.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!';
            }
        })
```

Here is the HTML code that was ran through it:

```
    <h3>How many innings was the longest baseball game in MLB history</h3>
    <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Input" id="userInput" type="text">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

But when I simply changed "let check" to: "document.querySelector('input');" the code worked as intended. Why did one work over the other?

Comment: can you provide the (or an example) of the HTML this is applied to?

Comment: It sounds like your input element doesn't have a `userInput` id.

Comment: Is your js [deferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer)? Maybe `getElementById` returns `check = null` because the document isn't fully loaded at the time and `querySelector`, being slower, works as intended

Comment: @NickSlash just added the HTML code, sorry I definitely should've added that in originally.

Comment: @CcmU I used document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){, which I believe makes sure that the file has fully loaded.

Comment: I still think that that does not guarantee 100% the intended behavior. To cite the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):
"`DOMContentLoaded` does not wait for stylesheets to load, however deferred scripts do wait for stylesheets, and the `DOMContentLoaded` event is queued after deferred scripts. Also, scripts which aren't deferred or async (e.g. `<script>`) will wait for already-parsed stylesheets to load."

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` returns the first found result which is why you're getting your input. However, `querySelector('input')` actually looks for ALL inputs.

Perhaps you're missing the `id` field on your input which is why you can't find it by searching for the `userInput` ID.

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is what I have for the input code: <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Input" id="userInput" type="text">

Comment: `querySelectorAll('input')` looks for all, `querySelector()` looks for the first instance

Comment: My point is that querying for 'input' looks for all inputs but this happens to work since `querySelector` returns the first result

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue you're facing is linked to the *timing* of those methods. I suggest you to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15046461/10301322), to better understand the differences.

Essentially, you need to know that `getElementById()` is much faster than `querySelector()` and that js code runs even if the document is not fully loaded.

It's very likely that your js code was executing while the document was being loaded and so `getElementById` returns `null` because it couldn't find the element specified. This problem could be resolved, as you did, by changing `getElementById` into `querySelector`, but **it is not a fully reliable solution**. Instead of that, you should [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer) your JavaScript or ensure that the thing you are searching is loaded in another way.